# Azure IoT module twin update gets reverted back

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

My layered deployment (single module) properties read as follows:

```
"properties": {
        "desired": {
            "PublishInterval": 2000,
            "OtherProperty": 1
            "layeredProperties": {}
        }
},
...
```

After the deployment is applied I would like to add a custom property on some of the devices using the Azure portal, so the result might look like so:

```
"properties": {
            "desired": {
                "PublishInterval": 2000,
                "OtherProperty": 1
                "layeredProperties": {
                    "instance-specific-property": 4000
                }
            }
    },
    ...
```

A few minutes later this property gets reverted back and we end up with an empty `layeredProperties` collection.

Following up on similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817920/iotedge-module-twin-update-gets-reverted) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/2914) Im starting to think that it is not possible to do this at all and if one needs some specific properties on devices there should be a *layered deployment* created for that.

Is there really no way of updating a module's twin desired properties but using a deployment? Seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the trick is to specify the desired properties in a layered deployment that target specific property object e.g.

```
"properties.desired.powerSettings": {
    "MaxChargePower": 5000,
    "MaxDischargePower": 10000
}
```

This is the "unchangeable" object and will get reverted back by the layered deployment. But this now allows adding additional settings to the root object (`properties.desired`) through e.g. Azure portal, and it would look something like this

```
"properties": {
        "desired": {
            "powerSettings": {
                "MaxChargePower": 5000,
                "MaxDischargePower": 10000
            },
            "instance-specific-property": 4000, // new property that won't get reverted/removed by the layered deployment
....
}
```

Tested and verified - works as expected.

*ref* [How to configure individual modules for 100+ edge devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471979/how-to-configure-individual-modules-for-100-edge-devices/62661466#62661466)