# Azure IoT Hub Free tier deployment limitation

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Situation:

I hit a throttling limitation of free tier IoT Hub where deployments are limited to **10**. This limitation is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#other-limits)
[image]

Failed deployments manifests itself

- when [Azure DevOps CI pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment?view=iotedge-2020-11) is used
  [image]
- Azure Portal
  [image]

Problem(s):

The error is pretty clear, but what I'm struggling to understand is whether the limit of 10 gets reset at some point or is that it - no more automatic deployments for this Edge device, ever? The documentation seems to suggest that paid for IoT Hubs have 100 deployment limit, what do developers do after that?

I have created a deployment manifest and attempted to [deploy it manually through VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-modules-vscode?view=iotedge-2020-11). This has worked, but then within very short period of time (~5min) the Hub reverts to previous configuration. Is that because of this limit or its a property of the Hub to e.g. *revert to previous configuration if newly deployed modules fail for one reason or another*?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a deployment for every device. Rather target deployments to a set of devices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-at-scale?view=iotedge-2020-11

To modify a single device, follow the steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-modules-portal?view=iotedge-2020-11
This allows you to change every one of your max 1 million devices per IoT Hub individually. But is this really needed?

Best practice: Use layered deployments (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring?view=iotedge-2020-11) and change settings via Module Twin, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, @René. 
Not sure how the first link contributes to an answer.  I have no issue targeting devices. The Second link - I've tried and it doesn't work because of the limitation I described. The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817920/iotedge-module-twin-update-gets-reverted) question seems to suggest Layered deployments as your last link. But this doesn't answer why/how can I do manual deployment using VS Code or whether that's not possible now because of the throttling

Comment: The difference is between deployments (where limits apply) and configuration changes (where limits to not apply).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/edge/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest for deployments and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/edge?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-edge-set-modules for configuration (aka. set modules).

Comment: Thanks, @René. Just so I understood you correctly, what youre saying is since I hit the limit I wont be able to use automatic deployment (scale or layered) but I can still update the modules through *az iot edge set-modules* command?

Comment: Ive used *az iot edge set-modules* command. It set modules on the device and it reverted back a minute later to what it was in the last automatic deployment.

Comment: Automated deployments will overwrite manually set configurations. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring?view=iotedge-2020-11#target-condition for conditions.